# Where is implemented the Apple App Transport Security

Tags: ios, app-transport-security

Is the Apple App Transport Security feature implemented in CFNetwork or maybe it is a part of sandbox or system ?

Comment: Apple App Transport Security is part of the system.

Comment: @Lehlohonolo_Isaac ok, in which macOS an iOS private framework or kernel extension I can find it? How do you learned about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

App Transport Security (ATS) is enforced by the NSURLSession class and all APIs that use it. ATS is automatically enabled when you link your app against the iOS 9.0 SDK or later or against the macOS 10.11 SDK or later. (The older NSURLConnection class also enforces ATS when you link against the iOS 9.0 SDK or later or against the macOS 10.11 SDK or later.) ATS protections are not available when using lower-level networking APIs provided by Apple, or when using third-party networking libraries. [Source](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CocoaKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009251-SW55)